# Unable to Convert Time to Datetime using JodaTime Android

Tags: java, android, jodatime

i have a Time text field where the user can enter 9:30 AM or 9:30 PM in the text field, once they click the button for the next activity, i need to store that time in a DateTime field, the problem i am running into is, i cannot use DateTime.parse("9:30 AM") (using joda time) to convert the time to a DateTime variable.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

This is part of the code i am trying to use

```
Classx x = new Classx();
```

Note: the value of "at" in the textbox is 9:30 PM

```
String d = at.getText().toString();
x.xTime = DateTime.parse(d);
```

at is a EditText with the "Time" setting checked.
Classx is the class where the variables are stored.

Classx Layout

```
public class Classx extends AttributeContainer implements KvmSerializable
{

    public org.joda.time.DateTime xTime;

    public String C;

    public org.joda.time.DateTime Date;
}
```

NOTE: All variable names have been changed to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joda-Time, a time value is represented by a `LocalTime` object. Here is an example of reading in the string you gave as an example:

```
String inputTime = "9:30 PM";

DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
builder.appendPattern("h:mm a");

LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(inputTime, builder.toFormatter());
```

If you need to somehow combine this with an existing `DateTime`, you can do this:

```
DateTime orig = DateTime.now(); // or whatever    
DateTime dt = orig.withTime(time);
```